# Github pages not rendering css correctly for Jekyll theme

Tags: css, jekyll, github-pages

This is the link to github for the theme which I'm working on: https://github.com/PrashantYadav/xosjapps

On the localhost, its working properly.
I have set the baseurl but still its rendering css correctly as you can see it here - https://prashantyadav.github.io/xosjapps/

This is the url for original theme: https://github.com/jeromelachaud/freelancer-theme

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The console said that it's failed to load ressources. Are you sure you put the correct path to the files ?[image]

Comment: Actually, I'm doing it for the first time, so there can be mistakes, but as you see, it is displaying website here: https://prashantyadav.github.io/xosjapps/   but the css is not rendering properly. Also in _config.yml I've set url: https://prashantyadav.github.io/ and baseurl:  /xosjapps

Answer (score 0):

CSS files aren't being loaded properly.

Move your css files that are located in `/_includes/css` to `/css` and load them from your layout file (or include) as:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ '/css/main.css' | absolute_url }}" type="text/css" /> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ '/css/bootstrap.min.css' | absolute_url }}" type="text/css" />
```